# Finding out types of variables in Julia

Tags: types, julia

In Python it is possible to debug a program by analyzing data types by printing out a variable's type, such as
`print type(test_var)`

Is there something similar in Julia? I am having trouble assigning values to a 2-D array, and knowing the exact types of each variable would help.

Comment: Are you looking for the function `typeof()`? :)

Comment: eltype(test_var) also does the job

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You want [`typeof`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/?highlight=typeof#Base.typeof) and possibly also [`isa`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/?highlight=typeof#Base.isa):

```
julia> a = 2
2

julia> typeof(a)
Int64

julia> typeof("haha")
String

julia> typeof(typeof("haha"))
DataType

julia> typeof(Set([1,3,4]))
Set{Int64}

julia> 1 isa Number
true

julia> 1 isa String
false

julia> "1" isa Number
false

julia> "1" isa String
true
```

You might also want to use [`@show`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/?highlight=typeof#Base.@show)
as a convenient way to print debug info.